# output format - array missing

Tags: arrays, py-datatable

I am having a problem with displaying all the columns of the array. only 2 columns are displayed instead of 8.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9ISD.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll add this as an answer. My guess would be you would be able to see all your data if you print the df/array instead. Incase you want to display it, then using pandas and setting this value should do the trick

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

Comment: oh, thanks a lot it worked.